# Javascript / PHP Перейти по ссылке и заполнить форму

Tags: php, javascript

Всем Привет, есть такая задача.

у нас есть ссылка

```
var link = "example.com/somelink"
```

или на php

```
$link = "example.com/somelink";
```

нужно написать метод, который перейдет по ссылке, заполнит поля в открывшейся форме и нажмет кнопку submit.

что - то наподобие того что есть в тестовом фреймворке codeception.

> Вопрос в следующем, как называются плагины / движки для реализации
>   такой задачи на javascript / php ?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно это делается проще - просто отправляйте запрос сразу туда, куда отсылается форма, в том же виде, в каком он отсылается, если отсылать форму. Это можно сделать и на php (с помощью curl, например) и на js (ajax/fetch/если надо заголовки подделать - то из nodejs).

Посмотреть, какие поля, какой метод, какие заголовки, и куда отправляется интересующий вас запрос, можно во вкладке network  в консоли браузера

Comment: Этот метод не подходит, нужно после заполнения форм также нажать кнопку submit на стороннем сайте и получить результат.

Нужен именно вариант наподобие как у codeception

Comment: @S1lllver Почему не подходит? В чем проблема?